# How to search elements between two ranges in C# with Characters and numbers combination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have a requirement like a search functionality in my module, We need to search between two ranges when the user is giving input like below scenario.

The column name is "Name" which has been defined as `varchar` in Oracle 11G DB.
UI column name is NAME.

Example Column Name : A5000C0,A5000C2,A5000C3,A5000C4,A5000C5,A5000C6

So when the user is trying to search using the name field ranges like A5000C0- A5000C6, the result should be the elements between the range A5000C1 to A5000C6.

PS: there are situations users can search like between the range A5000C1 to A5001C6

How to do this in C#? Our module is based on ASP.Net MVC5 using c# and for search expression, we are using NHibernate to form the expression.

Comment: maybe need [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) or [Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Comment: You're going to have to explain your naming scheme a little. For example, is it only the last character they can check the range for?

Comment: @itsme86 no there are situations users can search like between the range A5000C1 to A5001C6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alpha Numeric Search of Values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327250/alpha-numeric-search-of-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: domsson there my exact question was edited because of the reason like asking code conversion so edited my question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your question that got removed. Try this code if you like. It's converted to C# but you should really look it over before you use it.

```
public static HashSet<string> GetNamesFromRangeQuery(string multipleIds)
{
    multipleIds = multipleIds.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "");

    HashSet<string> inSet = new HashSet<string>();

    string[] parts = multipleIds.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^M([0 - 9] +)C([0 - 9] +)$");
        Regex rgxTwo = new Regex(@"^M([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)-M([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)$");
        Regex rgxThree = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
        Regex rgxFour = new Regex(@"^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$");

        if (rgx.IsMatch(part))
        {
            inSet.Add(part);
        }
        else if (rgxTwo.IsMatch(part))
        {
            string[] fromTo = part.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo[0].Substring(1, fromTo[0].IndexOf("C")));
            int mTo = int.Parse(fromTo[1].Substring(1, fromTo[1].IndexOf("C")));

            int cFrom = int.Parse(fromTo[0].Substring(fromTo[0].LastIndexOf("C") + 1));
            int cTo = int.Parse(fromTo[1].Substring(fromTo[1].LastIndexOf("C") + 1));

            for (int i = mFrom; i <= mTo; i++)
            {
                for (int j = cFrom; j <= cTo; j++)
                {
                    inSet.Add("M" + i + "C" + j);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (rgxThree.IsMatch(part))
        {
            inSet.Add(part);
        }
        else if (rgxFour.IsMatch(part)

            {
            string[] fromTo = part.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int from = int.Parse(fromTo[0]);
            int to = int.Parse(fromTo[1]);

            for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
            {
                inSet.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inSet.Add(part);
        }
    }

    return inSet;
}
```

Comment: Great that you helped me in this case, Let me try and it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting the below error on, int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo[0].Substring(1, fromTo[0].IndexOf("C")));  Error : Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Hard to say, try to debug and check the value of: "string[] fromTo" before int.Parse

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, It was because of when its doing indexOf with C also get joined so I did, (C) -1, now its working fine without any issues. Thanks a lot Eric you made my day so great it was longtime pending issue but you helped me to resolve. PS: I am making changes in your answer and making it as answer for this thread hope you wont mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get the point. It looks like an alphabetical string comparison, doesn't it?

So something like this should do it:

```
public IList<Entity> SearchRange(string lower, string upper)
{
    return _session.Query<Entity>()
        .Where(e => e.Name.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 and e.Name.CompareTo(upper) <= 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

This example uses [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) and requires NH v3.3.3. The `CompareTo` will be translated to a `case when` statement. If you rather use direct comparisons, use [hql](/questions/tagged/hql):

```
public IList<Entity> SearchRange(string lower, string upper)
{
    return _session
        .CreateQuery("from Entity e where e.Name between :lower and :upper")
        .SetString("lower", lower)
        .SetString("upper", upper)
        .List<Entity>();
}
```

The HQL query could be written `from Entity e where e.Name >= :lower and e.Name <= :upper` too.

Comment: No, My requirement is comparison but not like lower and uppercase values

Comment: `lower` and `upper` in my answer are not about casing but about your range bounds.